# How can I integrate SQL Server with MSSCCI provider for tfs 2013&2015?

Tags: sql-server, version-control, tfs, msscci

I was trying to use Team Foundation Server 2012 with Sql Server Management Studio 2012. I installed the *Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2013 & 2015 MSSCCI Provider 32-bit* and choose it as *Current source control plug-in* under tools -> Source Control -> Plug-in Selection of SSMS.

The problem is when I create/open a solution, for the very first time, and try to add a solution to source control from **file -> source control -> Add Solution to Source Control** a dialog box appears asking to connect to tfs once connected and location of server is specified on server and *ok button* is pressed it shows a warning that my workspace is a local workspace and local workspaces do not work properly in MSSCCI. It asks if I want to change it to server workspace once I click on *Yes*

I get the following error

**Unexpected error encountered. It is recommended that you restart the application as soon as possible.

Error: No such interface supported

File: Vsee\internal\inc\vscomptr.inl

Line number: 259**

Trying again yield this error message as soon as I choose **Add Solution to Source Control**.

I have tried some of the hotfixes provided by Microsoft from the link :
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2727824 but they do not install on my machine saying that my SSMS version is newer.

How can I get this problem resolved ?

Comment: What's the system version are you using? Which version of TFS are you working with? I tried on a 64-bit Windows Server 2012 R2 with SQL Server 2014 Management Studio installed, then install Team Explorer 2013 and Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2013 & 2015 MSSCCI Provider 32-bit to work with TFS 2015.  After installing MSSCCI Provider, New a solution/project in SSMS and add to source control, no issue occurred. You may try to remove Team Explorer/VS and MSSCCI Provider on your machine, and reinstall them, to see whether the issue persists.

Comment: I am using Windows 7 64-bit and Team Foundation Server 2012. Were you able to successfully add a project to tfs ?

Comment: Yes, I can add a project to TFS successfully. You may try to remove Team Explorer/VS and MSSCCI Provider on your machine, and reinstall them, to see whether the issue persists.

Comment: It was probably some configuration problem on my machine, on another system it was working fine. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

As described in [this article](http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/sql-server-source-control-part-ii-integration/) - Team Foundation Server 2012 brought up a change in the workspace options bringing a new type of workspace – a local workspace. A local workspace is an improvement in offline work and it allows performing a number of source control operations without the connection to Team Foundation Server.

For more information about server workspaces vs. local workspaces refer to the following article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phkelley/archive/2013/05/29/server-workspaces-vs-local-workspaces.aspx

The article states that Microsoft continues to fully support the older kind of workspaces (from VS/TFS 2005 - 2010), but they now call these “server” workspaces. In the VS/TFS 2005 - 2010 documentation there is no mention of these workspaces ever being called “server workspaces” – because before the existence of local workspaces, there was no need to have a special name for them - they were just “workspaces.”

Hope I helped.

Answer (score 2):

I am using TFS Online (Visual Studio Online), SQL Server Management Studio 2012, Windows Server 2008 R2, and installed Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2013&2015 MSSCCI Provider 32 bit. I can add new solution in SSMS and add to source control with no issue. You might want to 
1. go back and create the server workspace *FIRST* in Team Explorer 2012. 
2. Then re-create the solution (Make sure you check the Add to Source Control), 
3. then select the TFS with the correct server workspace. 
4. from Solution Explorer, right click on the project and add existing items.

Hope it helps